# Meteor app crashing localhost:3000

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

I am trying to run  boostrap/metetor files. I am getting this error

Your app is crashing. Here's the latest log.

```
C:\Users\andrew\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\server-lib\node_modules\fibers\future.js:245
                        throw(ex);
                              ^
Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery
    at app\bootstrap-3.3.4-dist\js\bootstrap.js:8:9
    at app\bootstrap-3.3.4-dist\js\bootstrap.js:2319:3
    at C:\Users\andrew\Desktop\teetimesM\teetimesM\.meteor\local\build\programs\server\boot.js:222:10
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Function._.each._.forEach (C:\Users\andrew\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\server-lib\node_modules\underscore\underscore.js:79:11)
    at C:\Users\andrew\Desktop\teetimesM\teetimesM\.meteor\local\build\programs\server\boot.js:117:5
Exited with code: 8
Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.
```

I have all jQuery tags included as well as tags to all js files.

>

Where am I missing or how do I correct this?

Comment: the simplest way to include bootstrap is with a package like ` meteor add twbs:bootstrap`. Must be a load order issue of some sort.

Comment: yes, I am using a bootstrap plugin

Comment: I followed the instructions on install as such here. http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Installing/

Comment: my tags are <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap-3.3.4-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="teetimesM.js"></script>

Comment: Are you install the meteor jquery package? `meteor add jquery`

Comment: I did not add that, thank you for pointing it out. I added it. However I am still getting the error.

Comment: @AndySchoenherr: Just start the project from scratch, it's best to add Bootstrap using the package. Meteor already includes jQuery.

Comment: You can try `meteor reset; meteor update; meteor run`

Comment: @AndySchoenherr - Welcome to stack overflow! If an answer is helpful, generally the way the site works is you should mark it as correct, but only if it answered your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to add a jQuery package (it's bundled with meteor), or add any script tags. Remove your script tags, and just enter `meteor add twbs:bootstrap` at the terminal in your app directory (or use your preferred bootstrap package).